# 'default_author' cannot be null' Error when saving channel settings

Tags: control-panel, channel, settings

It is an upgraded site that runs now on EE 5.2.0 without major troubles.

Only when I save channel settings in the CP there is always this error message. Data is saved but this is the message:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'default_author' cannot be null:
UPDATE `exp_channel_form_settings` SET `default_author` = NULL WHERE `channel_form_settings_id` = '1'
```

What do I need to do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. I've noticed it too, in EE4. I actually forgot about and have been too busy to file an issue.

You just have to make sure you select a default author when changing the Channel settings.

I actually don't have a bleeding edge install anywhere, and it looks like the github repo will close bug reports for legacy versions, so would you or anyone else with EE5.2.0 mind filing a bug report on github?

https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/issues/new/choose

Comment: OK, I filed the bug on github.

Comment: Thanks! I just commented and hopefully the core team will notice and act on this issue.